# Folder App/code and App/design Difference?

Tags: module, blocks, magento-1

when i turned on template path hints, i saw the .phtml links forex:

```
frontend\base\default\template\page/1column.phtml
```

which means  `page` is the module which located on `app/design/frontend\base\default\layout\page.xml`

so i thought the block settings is on the XML while the code is on the template path

on the other hand when i turned on Add block name to hints it came out `Mage_Page_Block_Html` which i can found on App\code\core/mage/page/block/html.php

so i thought the block code is on `1column.pthml` and what is `html.php` code contains? why is it differs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

app/code contains all class files in that where you can create your own module to.

app/design contains all phtml files language file and layout files

Answer (score 1):

There is no `app/skin` folder.

The `skin` folder is/should always be located under the root folder, on the same level as the `app` folder. Otherwise Magento won't work correctly.

Maybe you mean the `app/design` folder?

In any case:

- `app/code` holds the logic for the Magento core and custom modules
- `app/design` holds layout and template files both for Magento core and custom modules
- `skin` folder has the CSS, JS and images

Comment: that reminds me, i'm mistaken skin for design. thanks mate

Comment: what i'm asking is why template hints and block names is pointing to a different php/phtml files? 1 block points to 2 different code is making me confuse